# split integer add decimal point and return value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My integer value is like below and

```
    var amount= 5501; 
    var amount= 5500;
    var amount= 5560;
    var amount= 5563;
    var amount= 5510;
```

i want split this integer like below .Have to add decimal point on middle. if last digit 0 not consider.

amount and should come "55.0.1"
amount and should come "55.0"
amount and should come "55.6"
amount and should come "55.6.3"
amount and should come "55.1"

i tried this ,

var variable1 = 5500;

```
function versionss(variable1){
var digits = (""+variable1).split("");
if(Number(digits[3] > 0)){
    return  Number(variable1/100) ; //
} else {
    return digits[0]+digits[1]+'.'+digits[2];
}

}
```

Comment: are they always 4 digits long?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Number.isInteger()`

```js
function versionss(amount) {
  var divisor = Number(amount) > 999 ? 100 : 10;
  var value = amount / divisor;
  return Number.isInteger(value) ? value.toFixed(1) : value;
}

console.log(versionss(5501)); 
console.log(versionss(5500)); 
console.log(versionss(5560)); 
console.log(versionss(5563)); 
console.log(versionss(5510));
```

Comment: Hi one more change i need, If its 5501 means i want to split 55.0.1 and 5500 means 55.0. last digit more than 0 then need one more decimal

Comment: What you are asking is something not parallel to this question. You can ask a new question with what have you tried

Comment: If fourth digit more than ZERO means i want to split with 2 decimal points.. 5501 => 55.0.1 and 5500 => 55.0